# How can I change a map while ROS is running?

Tags: navigation, mapping, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

right now I am navigating through a map.
But I want to change this map while ROS is running due to a floor change.
Is there a way, for example in C++, to change the map in code?

regards
max

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12418/how-can-i-change-a-map-while-ros-is-running?/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2011-12-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're using Electric, the navigation stack supports [dynamic_reconfigure](http://www.ros.org/wiki/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials). That's probably the easiest way to do what you want to do.

If you're using Diamondback, you might have a lot more difficulty. Most of the parameters of move_base in Diamondback are a one-time read, and thus require a restart of the node to re-initialize.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-12-22**:
Dynamic reconfigure can be done with C++. costmap_2d is a good example if you're looking to see some code implemented.

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2011-12-22**:
If using a C++ node is there a way to use dynamic_reconfigure to change the map? So far I have only been able to do that from Python.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, our best solution was to move 2 maps in 1.
So the map.png has 2 maps in it and when you want to change the map you simply set a new position to the other map.

---

Originally posted by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) with karma: 496 on 2012-05-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1